# TideSDK google fonts support

Tags: tidesdk, google-webfonts

I'm facing some problems with the google fonts, using TideSDK.
I took a code snippet, 100% working, from a previous web project I did.

CSS3 code:

```
body {
font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

}

HTML5 code:

```
<!-- Google Fonts link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open%20Sans">
```

I've seen that this question has been asked already here on stackoverflow, but since that the answers I've found are a bit outdated and closed, I tought that it was a good idea to open a new one regarding this topic.

The question is: how can I implement google fonts into the TideSDK app? Because the same snipppet that I've taken from a previous tested web app here doesn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Oh, you're right, sorry. I edited the topic, now there's the question. :D